# function that return const and core dump

Tags: c++

**Hello everyone**

This is my first question, related to C++ University Course

I tried playing with the initialization of strings and got the following results, I'd love to know why this is happening ( the results are in comments )

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const string foo() {}
int main() {
    const string a = foo();
    string b = foo(); // Will make core dump
    const string& c = foo(); // Will make core dump
    string& d = foo(); // Compile error
    const string& e = "HEY"; // Will make core dump
}
```

**Thanks!**
Note: Its not a valid code

used as an exercise in the University

Comment: `foo()` does not return anything making the behavior of the whole program undefined.

Comment: you cannot refer to an rvalue

Comment: you should get a warning for `foo`

Comment: If you aren't compiling with warnings enabled, you should. And put MSVC into non-permissive mode, `d` is invalid in standard C++.

Comment: Your function foo does not return anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior)

Answer (score 2):

```
const string a = foo();
string b = foo(); // Will make core dump
const string& c = foo(); // Will make core dump
string& d = foo(); // Compile error
```

All of these invoke undefined behavior because `foo()` is declared to return `const std::string` but it doesn't, the result of the program is irrelevant.

Comment: Assuming that the function returns a valid std::string, why the following line cause Compile error?  string& d = foo();

Comment: @TzviMints because lvalue reference to non const cannot be bound to an rvalue.

Comment: @TzviMints The better question is: what do you *expect* that line to do? You're creating a reference to a (very) temporary value.

Comment: Got it, thanks! @SilvioMayolo

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const string foo() {
    return string();// TODO return sth useful
}
int main() {
    const string a = foo();
    string b = foo(); 
    const string c = foo();
    string d = foo();
    const string d2 = "HEY";
}
```

let's take a look what you were doing wrong:

```
const string& c = foo();
```

you are initializing a `reference` with an `rvalue`, the compiler will prevent that, because the result of `foo()` is a **temporary**.

```
string& d = foo();
```

the same problem as above.
and

```
string& d = foo(); // Compile error
const string& d = "HEY"; // Will make core dump
```

you are redefining `d` in the same scope not possible.

and above all your function doesn't return anything, that's undefined behavior:

```
const string foo() {}
```